# include null check to find index in list

Tags: c#, linq

Can I include a check for null in this code:

```
var index = someList.FindIndex(p => p.Bla1.Id == Dto.Id || p.Bla2.Id == Dto.Id);
```

Bla1 and Bla2 can both be null. Thanks.

Comment: What do you exactly want to check for? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I think its fairly self-explanatory ...

Comment: Misunderstood your question. I understood that IDs could be null, not objects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this:

```
var index = someList.FindIndex(p => (p.Bla1 != null && p.Bla1.Id == Dto.Id) 
                                 || (p.Bla2 != null && p.Bla2.Id == Dto.Id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can =)

If you ask for how to do this:

```
var index = someList.FindIndex(p => (p.Bla1 != null && p.Bla1.Id == Dto.Id) || (p.Bla2 != null && p.Bla2.Id == Dto.Id));
```

But all depends on how you want to handle nulls